# :hover picture swap isn't working

Tags: css, image, hover

What am I doing wrong? No picture is showing up at all. :-/ (fyi I cut off the bottom of the code, the tags are all completed I promise)

On all the tutorials I looked at they did this very thing and it showed the whole picture. But when I do it it doesn't show anything. If I type text inside the a href tags it shows part of the picture behind the text, but nothing otherwise.

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #ebf4f7;
    background-image: url(bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
#mainnav {
    position: relative;
    top: -9px;
    left: -2px;
    width: auto;
    padding-right: 0%;
    padding-left: 0%;
}
   .profilebutton {
    background-image: url(button%20profile.png);
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    height: 71px;
    width: 113px;
}
.profilebutton:hover {
    background-image: url(button%20profile.png);
    background-position: 0px 100%;
    height: 71px;
    width: 113px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav id="mainnav"> 
    <a href="my_profile.html" class="profilebutton"></a>
```

Comment: pretty sure you'd need display:block; on your profilebutton

Comment: When does the background image not show up - only on hover or all the time?

Comment: please get rid of those spaces in your file names ... shrug

Answer (score 1):

`<a>` is an inline element, so you have to give the property `display: block;` to your `<a>` element if you aren't going to add any text: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2uf9maxj/1/)

```
.profilebutton {
    display:block;
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/300/303');
    background-position: 0px 100%;
    height: 71px;
    width: 113px;
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #ebf4f7;
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/300/301');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
#mainnav {
    position: relative;
    top: -9px;
    left: -2px;
    width: auto;
    padding-right: 0%;
    padding-left: 0%;
}
.profilebutton {
    display:block;
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/300/302');
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    height: 71px;
    width: 113px;
}
.profilebutton:hover {
    display:block;
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/300/303');
    background-position: 0px 100%;
    height: 71px;
    width: 113px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="mainnav">
<a href="my_profile.html" class="profilebutton">nbvnbvnchdfg</a>
```

Comment: Accept it as the answer if it did.